# the method RetrieveTableDisplay() invokes a SQL query built using input coming from an untrusted source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-injection, fortify

The method `RetrieveTableDisplay()` invokes a SQL query built using input coming from an untrusted source. This call could allow an attacker to modify the statement's meaning or to execute arbitrary SQL commands.

```
string sql = 
    SqlHelper.GetSqlString(Constants.RetrieveTableDisplay) + tableName + 
    " WHERE ACCOUNT_NBR='" + AccountNumber + 
    "' ORDER BY " + GenerateOrderByClause(tableName) + " ) a ) where rn > " +
    (currentPageNumber * currentPageSize).ToString() + " AND rn <= " +
    ((currentPageNumber * currentPageSize) + currentPageSize).ToString();

string recordCount = 
    "select count(*) from " + tableName + 
    " WHERE ACCOUNT_NBR='" + AccountNumber + "'";
    //Issue is somewhere here of sql injection

if (!Utils.IsUnitTestCase)
{
    try
    {
        using (DbCommand cmd =
               OraDB.GetSqlStringCommand(this.ProcessTableName(sql)))
        {
            using (IDataReader reader = OraDB.ExecuteReader(cmd))
            {
                object o = OraDB.ExecuteScalar(CommandType.Text, recordCount);
                if (o != null)
                {
                    lstEntities.TotalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(o);
                }

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    objBasTransactionLog = new BASTransactionLog();
                    PopulateEntity(objBasTransactionLog, reader);

                    lstEntities.Add(objBasTransactionLog);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Recommendations:

The remedy is to never use string concatenation to build SQL statements. Prepared statements, also called placeholders, should be used to build SQL statements.

Comment: So you're dumping the result of a code audit here and expect us to fix it for you so you don't have to do _any_ effort at all to researching and solving this issue? Start again by reading the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: sorry that i asked this question to genius people like you. If you cant help atleast dont embarrass anybody. i have solved it by myself . But i feel pity on you that you are not having tym to resolve the issue but to embarrass yo have a lot of time.

Comment: The problem is that your question isn't answerable, because there's no question in it.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to guard against SQL injection is to use `SqlParameter`.
Do not add parameter values using string concatentation.

See [Using Parameters for SQL Server Queries and Stored Procedures](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/)